# Android - Cache Webpages in WebView

Tags: android, caching, android-webview

I am developing an app which relies on a single WebView to display information from multiple sites.

How would I cache the **last page** visited of a **particular domain** for three separate sites?

For example:

- User visits Page A and then Page B on Website A; app caches Page B only.
- User visits Page B on Website A and then Page C on Website B; app caches Page B on Website A AND Page C on Website B.

Effectively, the goal is for the user to load a page on one website and then another on a different website, but then be able to return to the first page (located on the first website) without the page having to reload (or losing the second page).

Answer (score 0):

Please try changing the cache max size.

```
webview.getSettings().setAppCacheMaxSize(1024*1024*8);
```

Comment: Sorry if my question was unclear, but I am not having trouble with the cache, I just need a hint on how and where to start.